# Error: Communication error: The Client failed to send packet. The socket has been shut down

Tags: sockets, amazon-web-services, performance-testing, loadrunner, load-generator

Steps followed to installed Load Agent on AWS.

1. Firewall Exception from controller for port 50500 , 54345, 443 and 3389 on load agent machine.
2. Installed Load Runner Setup [ as Load agent Process is also a part of Load Runner Setup]
3. Allowed all the programs [Agent Process, Agent Service.. etc] from Windows Firewall.
4. Tried to connect from Load Controller. Error received on controller is

Communication error: The Client failed to send packet. The socket has been shut down.

As per OPs team, the agent is trying to establish a connection back to a server 54.xxx.xx.xxx[Unknown AWS IP] on port 10051 and failing eventually where as this particular server is unknown to us.

Version of Loadrunner on Agent and Controller is same.

Please tell how do i have to install or configure MI LISTENER or AGENT PROCESS over firewall.

Comment: Try adding the site in the _Controller's trusted sites_  or _Turn down_ __Controller's firewall__ for the same if you have _access_. OR  request the supporting team which has access over the controller.

Comment: Have you added the controller IP and agent port to the AWS Security Group that the agent instance is running on, if not the controller will not be able to access the instance.

Comment: @Manubhargav i am still at the setup step where agent has to be connected to the controller , so adding the sites wont work in this case

Comment: @SeanN yes the controller IP and agent port are added to the agent's security group on AWS

Comment: And is the agent instance in a VPC? Does it have Internet access - test it by checking that you can browse to a public web site in a browser on the agent instance. If it is a private subnet of a VPC you won't have Internet access without a NAT.

Comment: @SeanN Yes the agent is connected to internet. I have narrowed the above problem as telnet from controller to agent is working fine on 50500 and 54345 but the controller software is not able to connect to agent process. Any light on the configuration ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, it was a firewall exception mess made by the IT department. The above mentioned steps will clearly allow a communication with the LR Controller and Agent.